# How can I tell whether I'm in a Jupyter notebook (new) or a nbclassic notebook, or a Jupyter lab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyter-nbclassic

It's possible to distinguish Jupyter lab from the other two via: `psutil.Process().parent().name()` (thanks to [How to detect whether in Jupyter Notebook or Lab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57173235/6837658)).

But how can I tell nbclassic notebook from a new? My plugin implementation is quite different for those two. I need a way to tell the difference automatically.

I would potentially need to distinguish those from Google Colab and vscode-jupyter in the future, but currently they are not in my priority list.

Comment: What is your plugin doing exactly?